# JavaScript: How to detect ES6 class has its own constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

How to detect whether EcmaScript class has its own constructor?
See code snippet below.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {   // <- Own constructor
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
  }
}


class Manager extends Person {
    // This class does not have it's own constructor
}
```

It seems there is no clear way to do this check.

Thank you all for time and help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means to have "its own constructor"? You do know that classes aren't real, right, but only syntactic sugar for functions and their prototypes?

Comment: @RayToal, see example. I need to figure out somehow that class `Person` has its own constructor and class `Manager` don't.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? It seems like what you are asking is to have access to the source code. In JavaScript, when you say `class` and `constructor` you are NOT making classes and constructors Instead you are defining a function and maybe adding things to its prototype. I really don't see how this question (while interesting) has a relevant answer, because classes aren't real in JavaScript. Are you asking whether at run time you can see what the source code looked like? I think it is impossible without major hacks....

Comment: @RayToal, you are right, there's no way to do what I want. I'm working on DI mechanism and needed to get constructor of the class. But unfortunately, constructor method === class definition, so I should find another way to do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

It's not bulletproof, but you could convert the constructor to a string, and see if it contains the word `constructor(` or something similar

```js
function hasOwnConstructor(instance) {
    var str = instance.constructor.toString();
    return /class(.*?[^\{])\{([\s\n\r\t]+)?(constructor[\s]+?\()/.test(str);
}

class thing1 { 
    method() { return this; }
}

class thing2 { 
    constructor(argument) { return this; }
}

var ins1 = new thing1();
var ins2 = new thing2();

console.log( hasOwnConstructor(ins1) ); // false
console.log( hasOwnConstructor(ins2) ); // true
```

False positives could still be possible, but the regex makes the check quite strict, so it's not very plausable.

Comment: Thanks, but I still need 100% solution.

Comment: This seems like a programmatic solution to determining whether or not a class contains a constructor

Comment: @AaronEverly, yes, but it's a weak check. Thare can be some commented code that contains fragment `constructor(` or something else, anything... Thats why this solution is not 100% safe.

Comment: @AlexChandler maybe create a regular expression or function that searches for the exact schema of the constructor function. Something that detects a class declaration and then looks for the constructor. Are you looking for a solution to parse rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes, one could make it a lot more robust by using a regex ^

Comment: @AaronEverly, I'm looking for 100% JS solution. i.e. check some class properties or something else...

Comment: @AlexChandler - I don't think there is one. There is no method that will tell you if a constructor exists, what it is etc. the best I think you can do is get the class as a string, and try to figure it out from that.

Comment: One problem: I use TypeScript and code can be generated with ES5 specification compatibility. So that `toString` solution will deal with regular JS function instead of class.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it? Why would it matter what happens in ES5, where classes aren't supported? Also, I have no idea what Typescript does to convert code, I don't use that crap.

Comment: Because code can be post-processed and it's syntax can differ for ES6 and ES5.

Comment: Again, I don't know what TypeScript does when it converts to ES5, you'll have to figure that out yourself, or ask another question regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the constructor function.

```
class Example {

    constructor(prop1, prop2) {

    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;

      }
    }
```

You can pass parameters to your class via the constructor function that establishes properties which can be globally referenced when creating a new instance.

This line would pass int 1 and "test" as values to prop1 and prop2:

```
const exampleVar = new Example(1, "test");
```

and might render something like:

```
<Example prop1=1 prop2="test" />
```

Hope this helps. If it has a constructor function, there is a constructor, if it does not have the constructor function, then there is no constructor.